# Setting a class __name__ declaratively

Tags: python, metaclass, python-datamodel, python-descriptors, python-object

Why can't you override a class name declaratively, e.g. to use a class name which is not a valid identifier?

```
>>> class Potato:
...     __name__ = 'not Potato'
...     
>>> Potato.__name__  # doesn't stick
'Potato'
>>> Potato().__name__  # .. but it's in the dict
'not Potato'
```

I thought maybe it was simply a case that this was overwritten after the class definition block completes.  But seems that's not true, because the name is writable yet apparently *not* set in the class dict:

```
>>> Potato.__name__ = 'no really, not Potato'
>>> Potato.__name__  # works
'no really, not Potato'
>>> Potato().__name__  # but instances resolve it somewhere else
'not Potato'
>>> Potato.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__',
              '__name__': 'not Potato',  # <--- setattr didn't change that
              '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'no really, not Potato' objects>,
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'no really, not Potato' objects>,
              '__doc__': None})
>>> # the super proxy doesn't find it (unless it's intentionally hiding it..?)
>>> super(Potato).__name__
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Questions:

1. Where does `Potato.__name__` resolve?
2. How is `Potato.__name__ = other` handled (inside and outside of a class definition block)?

Comment: This feels very much like the name vs what-it's-called discussion in Through the Looking Glass. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks'_Eyes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Where does `Potato.__name__` resolve?

Most documented dunder methods and attributes actually exist in the native code side of the object. In the case of CPython, they are set as pointers in a slot in a C Struct defined in the object model.  (defined here - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04e82934659487ecae76bf4a2db7f92c8dbe0d25/Include/object.h#L346 , but with fields easier to visualize when one actually creates a new class in C, like here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04e82934659487ecae76bf4a2db7f92c8dbe0d25/Objects/typeobject.c#L7778 , where the "super" type is defined)

Therefore, `__name__` is set there by the code in `type.__new__`, to which it is the first parameter.

> How is `Potato.__name__` = other handled (inside and outside of a class definition block)?

A class's `__dict__` parameter is not a plain dictionary - it is an special mapping proxy object, and the reason for that is exactly so that all attribute settings on the class itself don't go through the `__dict__`, and instead go through the `__setattr__` method in type. In there, assignments to these slotted dunder methods are actually filled in the C object's C structure, and then reflected on the `class.__dict__` attribute.

So, **outside** a class block, `cls.__name__` is set in this way - as it takes place after the class has been created.

**Inside** a class block, all attributes and methods are collected into a plain dict (though that can be customized). This dict is passed to `type.__new__` and other metaclass methods - but as said above, this method fills in the `__name__` slot from the explicit passed `name` parameter (that is, the "name" argument passed in the call to `type.__new__`)- even though it just updates the class  `__dict__` proxy with all names in the dict used as namespace.

That is why `cls.__dict__["__name__"]` can start with a different content from what is in the `cls.__name__` slot, but subsequent assignments put both in sync.

An interesting anecdote is that three days ago I came across some code trying to reuse the `__dict__` name explicitly in the class body, which has similarly puzzling side-effects.
I even wondered whether there should be a bug report on that, and queried the Python developers - and as I had thought of, the authoritative answer was:

> ...all `__dunder__` names are reserved for the implementation and they should
> only be used according to the documentation. So, indeed, it's not illegal,
> but you are not guaranteed that anything works, either.
> (G. van Rossum)

And it applies just the same to trying to define `__name__` in the class body.

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2018-April/152689.html

---

And if one actually wants to override `__name__` as an attribute in the classbody, a metaclass for that is a simple as a metaclass can be:

```
class M(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kw):
         name = namespace.get("__name__", name)
         return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kw)
```